# Is it possible to redirect telescope to subdirectory

Tags: telescope

I would like to redirect forum.domain.com to www.domain.com/forum so that I can increase my SEO power. I am totally new to this product. My app is deployed on heroku(the files are not under the domain.com) and on the settings page in heroku i added my domain as following:

forum.domain.com --- myappname.herokuapp.com

and in my hosting provider which hosts the "domain" I changed the CNAME settings to following:

forum.domain.com --- myappname.herokuapp.com.

and also in the htaccess file I wrote this: RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.domain.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.domain/forum" [R=301,L]

I think that since CNAME for "forum" subdomain points to myappname.herokuapp.com I can't redirect forum.domain.com to www.domain.com/forum

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible in theory with heavy customizations, but Telescope is not set up to work in a subdirectory out of the box. So I don't think it would be very practical, sorry.